# How to add a character to the end of each line in a file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a script that add a particular character to the end of each line . I am using the command
sed 's/$/ foo/' r.txt

It adds foo to end of each line in the file r.txt and displays in my terminal .
What do i need to do if i want to save this existing file with this new record appended after the end of each line .

Comment: Use: `sed -i.bak 's/$/ foo/' r.txt`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to save stdout to a file, or edit? Well, both approaches have been answered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To save to a new file:

```
sed 's/$/ foo/' r.txt > newfile.txt
```

To edit in place

```
sed -i 's/$/ foo/' r.txt
```